# php chrome desktop is not showing external css

Tags: php, css, phpdesktop

I'm using php chrome desktop to transform my website to a desktop application, but the issue is that it shows without external css, but when i use inline css it works ?

Comment: Are there any errors in Developer Tools console?

Comment: Yes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Either you have an error in your code or the feature you're using is not supported in the phpdesktop version you're using. Update to latest.